# Cascading validations in Spring using the default validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, kotlin

I'm doing manual validations of of my entity classes. Consider a person entity:

```
data class Person (
    @get:NotNull var firstName: String = ""
)
```

My validation logic sits in an abstract class that services can use.

```
abstract class Validator {
    protected fun validate(model: Any): ValidationResult {
        val factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
        val validator = factory.validator

        val validationResult = validator.validate(model).fold(ValidationResult()) { validationResult, violation ->
            val message = violation.propertyPath.toString() + " - " + violation.message
            validationResult.add(message)
            validationResult
        }

        // Raise a validation exeception
        if (validationResult.isValid()) {
            throw ValidationException(validationResult)
        }

        return validationResult
    }
}
```

This allows me to write a service like this.

```
class PersonService (): Validator() {
    fun save(person: Person) {
         validate(person)
         // more logic that assumes data is valid
         repository.save(person)
    }
}
```

The advantage is that I can add this validator to the services I plan to write in the future. This works well however lets make a change to the person class:

```
data class Person (
    @get:NotNull var firstName: String = "",
    var job: Job = Job()
)
```

Now we have a job class that belongs to Person. Job has its own validation.

```
data class Job (
    @get:NotNull var department: String = "",
    @get:Min(0) var salary: Integer = "",
)
```

What I would like is for my validator when called on the Job class as well. This would allow the validation logic to stay generic. Is there any way to cascade validation down to object members that are part of the original class that gets called

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at the following code:

```
class PersonService (): Validator() {
    fun save(person: Person) {
         validate(person)
         // more logic that assumes data is valid
         repository.save(person)
    }
}
```

Now we'll rewrite it using extension methods:

```
class PersonService (): Validator() {
    fun save(person: Person) {
         person.validate()
         // more logic that assumes data is valid
         repository.save(person)
    }
}
```

Stub of this function may look like this:

```
private fun Person.validate() {
    val factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
    val validator = factory.validator

    val validationResult = validator.validate(this).fold(ValidationResult()) { validationResult, violation ->
        val message = violation.propertyPath.toString() + " - " + violation.message
        validationResult.add(message)
        validationResult
    }

    // Raise a validation exeception
    if (validationResult.isValid()) {
        throw ValidationException(validationResult)
    }


    validationResult.addAll(job.validate())

    return validationResult
}
```

Job repeats the same pattern:

```
private fun Job.validate() {
   ...
}
```